# read data from a mysql server into "XCODE 4.6"

Tags: php, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5, webservice-client

I'm a STARTER in ios.I need to see the full code to read data from a mysql server into an iPhone/ipad in "XCODE 4.6".
I read through almost all similar pages in StackOverflow but I'm now confused and they are not working properly!
I went through scores of other websites but they are old and deprecated.Can someone please hep me out here ?

I need the standard and most updated code.

Comment: By "XCODE 4.6", do you mean that you need to download data from a webserver, running MySQL, in an iPhone/iPad/Mac application?

Comment: I've been at it for a week now !This is what i got so far:XCODE-(JSON or SOAP or XML)-PHP. I heard JSON is the simpler way.But nothing seem to work !

Comment: It can be very difficult when you are just starting out in the ios world, even if you are pretty accomplished in other technologies.  A good resource is Ray Wenderlich tutorial site.  You can check it out here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've made the code and it worked ! :

> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.php"];
>
> NSString *return= [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
>
> NSData *jsData = [return dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
>
> NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

However initWithContentsOfURL is deprecated and gave a warning.
Instead we have to use :

> - (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error 
>     or
> - (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedencoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error

but it is giving me a BAD ACCESS error.